# Phonegap with Android 4.4 scaling problems

Tags: android, cordova, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm developing a small game for Android with Phonegap. I'm using media queries to support 3 different screen sizes (width from 480 to 1920 px).
For Android version lower than 4.4 all works fine. But when I test it on a full HD resolution, Android displays all scaled like on a 480px screen. All seems to be very big. So having a full HD resolution does no make any sense.
Well, setting the target SDK version to 18 fixes the problem, but I would like to known what is happening there.
The documentation says, Android is scaling all to fit on the page. But why does it scale so much? Why not for higher resolution? There is no code that could explain this. I made the media queries especially to handle different resolutions.

Comment: What META tags are you using in your index.html page, if any?

Comment: Only this one: <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />